# Make Form responsive according to monitor screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I have designed Windows Form according to My monitor screen. When I installed my application on other PC with Different Screen size, the Form controls has been disturbed over Form, as most buttons goes out of Screen.

PS, Since I made default WindowState to Maximized, it do not show scroll bar.

I want to make UI responsive on any screen size

Comment: You should look for `Anchor` property on the controls. It will help you to resize the controls according to the size of the forms. If you are looking for re-positioning of the controls as per the size then you will need to write custom code for that.

Comment: WPF or UWP is much better at making "responsive" apps than WinForms is. It isn't impossible, but it is much more difficult.

Comment: Take a look at these topics: [Layout in Windows Forms Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/layout-in-windows-forms-controls) and [Windows Forms Layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951306.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Sorry, but [*if you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). This question is too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: What I would suggest is: Write a small example. Really minimal (one form, one button, hand-crafted; maybe 30 lines of code). In order to explain the problem take screen shots (you can post images here).  Then you'll have a specific question which may get answers. By the way, it is also a learning experience to hand-craft a windows forms program.

Comment: May this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937959/how-to-make-windows-forms-application-responisive-to-screen-resolution/48937960#48937960) helps you.